# Spark Dataframe: Spark dataframe saveAsTable LeaseExpiredException

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera-cdh

In my spark application I am saving a dataframe as a parquet file as follows,

```
comp_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("cdr_step1", format="parquet", path="/data/intermediate_data/cdr_step1/")
```

If my dataframe size is small this works fine. But as the dataset size increases I am getting the following error.
I checked this issue in the internet and in most places, people resolve this problem changing their code design. In my case I have only a single line of write operation and I don't understand what I need to change.

```
17/02/02 13:22:56 ERROR datasources.DefaultWriterContainer: Job job_201702021228_0000 aborted.
17/02/02 13:22:56 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 0 executor(s).
17/02/02 13:22:56 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1979.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 1984, slv3.cdh-prod.xxxx.com, executor 86): org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /data/intermediate_data/cdr_step1/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201702021322_0003_m_001979_0/part-r-01979-9fe33b7c-0b14-4e63-8e96-6e83aabbe807.gz.parquet (inode 2144221): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1523564925_148 does not have any open files.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3635)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:3438)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3294)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:679)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:214)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:489)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2086)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2082)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2080)
```

Comment: Do you have settings in spark.conf related to hive? Are you able to create physical tables from sqlcontext ?

Comment: How long the query is running?

Comment: @FaigB 
Yes. I can create tables as follow,
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING)")
But I am not sure it creates a physical tables or not.
About the spark.conf related to hive, I don't think I specifically defines any configurations, except the default cloudera distribution configurations.

Comment: @Serhiy
It runs more than 30 minitues to get this errror.

Comment: Maybe related to this bug.. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2984.. Have you tried updating Hadoop/Spark versions?

Comment: physical tables can be created only with hive support in spark. In such case that there is no hive support the saveTable command will create inmemory tables which will be temporary available.

Comment: does anyone have an answer or reference for this issue ?